# Powershell: For each loop loop with list issues

Tags: list, powershell, loops, foreach

I am trying to loop the list through the function that i made. What I want to do with the loop is that the variable: "$huidige_folder" inside the function is filled with one location at a time that is in the list, loop and continue with the next location in the list

1. So first item in the list: "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Test1". It uses
   this location in the function
2. Then C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Test2". It uses this location in the
   function
3. Then C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Test3". It uses this location in the
   function

But when i run the code it will only run the function for the first item in the list. That works and it does what i want.
But after that it stops and doenst run the funtion for the other 2 items in the list.

What am i doing wrong?

```
$path_dagelijkse_controle = "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Test1",
                            "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Test2", 
                            "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Test3"



function Dagcontrole_folders_maken {($huidige_folder)

$Dagelijkse_controle = "Dagelijkse controle"
$datum_vandaag = $(Get-Date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$jaar = $datum_vandaag.Substring(0,4)
$maand = $datum_vandaag.substring(5, 2)
$dag = (get-date).DayOfWeek

$path_jaar = Get-Item -Path "$huidige_folder\**" -Include *$jaar*
$path_maand = Get-Item -Path "$huidige_folder\$jaar\**" -Include *$maand*
$folder_maand = Get-Date -UFormat "%m - %B"


if ($path_jaar) {
    Write-Output "Do Nothing"
}
Else {   
    md -Path "$huidige_folder\$jaar"   
}

if ($path_maand) {
  md -Path "$huidige_folder\$jaar\$folder_maand\Dagelijks\$datum_vandaag"  
}
Else {
    md -Path "$huidige_folder\$jaar\$folder_maand"                              # Makes the month folder
    md -Path "$huidige_folder\$jaar\$folder_maand\Dagelijks\$datum_vandaag"     # Makes a folder with current date inside the month folder
}

}


Foreach ($i in $path_dagelijkse_controle) {
    Dagcontrole_folders_maken($i)
    }
```

Comment: Change `function Dagcontrole_folders_maken {($huidige_folder)` to `function Dagcontrole_folders_maken ($huidige_folder) {`

Comment: You can simplify your code substantionaly by using `md .. -Force`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the declaration of your function:

```
function Dagcontrole_folders_maken ([String]$huidige_folder) {
```

It means that `$huidige_folder` is declared as a String. But the main issue was the { character placed at the wrong place. It must be placed after the arguments.

I would also suggest you to parse all the elements within your function. You can write your ForEach into the function and give an array of strings as an argument. That way, your function would work with one or more elements.

```
function Dagcontrole_folders_maken ([String[]]$huidige_folder) {
ForEach($folder in $huidige_folder) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the parentheses around $i.

Unlike most languages, Powershell does not require parentheses around the actual parameters on a function call.  They may be doing harm.

Also, thanks to lieven Keersmaekers,  the left brace in the definition should be after the parameter definiton, not before it.